# Unable to click on the menubar

Tags: macos

Recently I edited a *.plist file of an App in order to hide it from the Dock. Everything works but I can't click on the menubar anymore when the App is selected..! Any help?

This is what I did

```
previously:

<key>LSUIElement</key>
<false/>

after:

<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

this is what I get: "resource envelope is obsolete (custom omit rules)" what does it mean?

Comment: see this answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52902/46541

Comment: this is what I get: "resource envelope is obsolete (custom omit rules)"
what does it mean?

Comment: it means just that, you changed a app and now it is no longer approved by osx (code signed)

Comment: Is there any alternative to the edit of LSUIElement?

Answer (score 1):

When you set "LSUIElement" to true, it makes the application in question a semi GUI-less application.  While calling up the application in this state, it still shows up windows, but it does neither show its Dock icon nor its menu bar.

As to alternatives: The only real alternative is to have the application support this on its own (e.g. inside its own GUI).

Keep in mind that enabling "LSUIElement" (a.k.a. setting it to true) is not telling the application to hide its Dock icon, but rather tells the Dock not to show the application's icon while it is running.  Also GUI-wise there are two main processes running for the user: Finder and the Dock.  The first is merely an application on its own and will allow you to browse and alter the files on your computer and the latter besides showing and controlling the Dock icons controls the menu bar itself (not the menu items of each application, mind you) as well as the Dashboard and Launchpad among others. You can see its effect when running Terminal and type in "killall Dock".  It will effectively restart Dock and its depending items.